# 1st local boot of rails server is extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I have been programming in ROR for the last 15 years.

At this moment, I am using:

- puma 5.6.2
- gem 3.3.4
- rails 7.0.2.3
- ruby 3.0.0p0
- Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon
- Cinamon 4.8.6
- My Desktop CPU has an AMD 8cores processor and
  32 GB RAM

When I start programming, I open Terminator or xterm and type `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` and wait for almost 3 minutes for puma server to be ready. If I do Ctrl-C and retype the command, it takes less than 3 seconds to be ready.

I have been surfing on the net, investigating what is wrong, tried out every idea I found, and nothing seems to work.

This same situation happens in all the computers that I use to develop, like my laptop and my home desktop.

Even I created a new test app called *speedboot* with `rails new speedboot` to test if maybe the number of gems in my Gemfile was the problem. Then, inside `speedboot` directory run `rails s` and it takes 3 or more minutes for the server to be ready, so the number of gems in the Gemfile is not the problem.

Any ideas or suggestions would truly be appreciated

The output I get from `rails s` is:

```
  warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby30, which recognizes3.0.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 3.0.0.
  Please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
  /home/addicttux/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/control_d_handler.rb:5: warning: control_d_handler's arity of 2 parameters was deprecated (eval_string, pry_instance). Now it gets passed just 1 parameter (pry_instance)
  => Booting Puma
  => Rails 7.0.2.3 application starting in development 
  => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options

  up to date, audited 4 packages in 431ms

  found 0 vulnerabilities
  Puma starting in single mode...
  * Puma version: 5.6.2 (ruby 3.0.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
  *  Min threads: 5
  *  Max threads: 5
  *  Environment: development
  *          PID: 21740
  * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
  Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

---

Today, one day after the original post, I added the following code:

```
  puts "****** #{__FILE__} --- #{Time.now()} ******"
```

To the several files. This is what I got:

```
  ****** bin/rails --- 2022-04-07 18:28:41 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/boot.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:41 -0500 ******
  warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby30, which recognizes3.0.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 3.0.0.
  Please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
  /home/addicttux/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/control_d_handler.rb:5: warning: control_d_handler's arity of 2 parameters was deprecated (eval_string, pry_instance). Now it gets passed just 1 parameter (pry_instance)
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/application.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:52 -0500 ******
  => Booting Puma
  => Rails 7.0.2.3 application starting in development 
  => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/environments/development.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:53 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/assets.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:54 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:55 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/npm.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:55 -0500 ******

  up to date, audited 4 packages in 678ms

  found 0 vulnerabilities
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/routes.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:57 -0500 ******
  ****** config/puma.rb --- 2022-04-07 18:28:57 -0500 ******
  Puma starting in single mode...
  * Puma version: 5.6.2 (ruby 3.0.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
  *  Min threads: 5
  *  Max threads: 5
  *  Environment: development
  *          PID: 9121
  * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
  * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
  Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

As you can see, editing the files seems to solve the problem, but why? No idea.

---

What a big disappointment. Again the server startup is very slow. I still can't find the reason. I share the time it throws at me when loading my server.

**Commands:** `date; rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

**Output:**

```
  sáb 09 abr 2022 12:29:36 CDT
  ****** bin/rails --- 2022-04-09 12:31:07 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/boot.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:31:07 -0500 ******
  warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby30, which recognizes3.0.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 3.0.0.
  Please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
  /home/addicttux/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/control_d_handler.rb:5: warning: control_d_handler's arity of 2 parameters was deprecated (eval_string, pry_instance). Now it gets passed just 1 parameter (pry_instance)
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/application.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:16 -0500 ******
  => Booting Puma
  => Rails 7.0.2.3 application starting in development 
  => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/environments/development.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:17 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/assets.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:22 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:22 -0500 ******
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/initializers/npm.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:22 -0500 ******
  up to date, audited 4 packages in 1s
  found 0 vulnerabilities
  ****** /home/addicttux/Desarrollos/GrupoSerton/sags/config/routes.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:26 -0500 ******
  ****** config/puma.rb --- 2022-04-09 12:35:28 -0500 ******
  Puma starting in single mode...
  * Puma version: 5.6.2 (ruby 3.0.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
  *  Min threads: 5
  *  Max threads: 5
  *  Environment: development
  *          PID: 8135
  * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
  Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: What is happening while you wait? Is there a log output? Does it "hang" on a specific part?

Comment: Nothing happens, the computer does not hang.

Comment: I am even using [Bumbler Gem](https://github.com/mark-ellul/Bumbler) to get some kind of output while booting up the server, and it lets me see that it has not been hanged

Comment: "Nothing happens", or "It does not hang"? Which one is it? It can't be both.

Comment: Is anything being printed to the log while the server starts? Yes ==> What is it printing? No ==> This means it's hanging. What was the last line that printed?

Comment: I just added the output of `rails s` to the question

Comment: @OfficeYA maybe a decade out of date bumbler gem is the issue, or something else you have that slows the world. i assume all your computers use the same setup scripts, so nothing is different from computer to computer. try a fresh ruby install, without any gems and any default gems you install with ruby; then add your global gems one by one. use `ruby-prof` or something similar to get useful stats.

Comment: @Alex, 1) with or without bumbler gem, same result, extremely slow. 2) the fresh new app that I created (called speedboot), without doing any editing to any file, is as slow as the one I am working on with 89 gems

Comment: @OfficeYA Perhaps you don't understand my question. You said that you must "wait for almost 3 minutes for puma server to be ready". When you run `rails s`, the log looks normal, but at what step is it "waiting for 3 minutes"? Is this before it prints anything? After the line "warning: parser/current is loading..."? After the line " => Booting Puma"? Or does the entire log print almost immediately, but somehow the server still doesn't actually work for 3 minutes?

Comment: I got it. After `rails s` it takes about 1.5 minutes for "warning: ...", then it takes about 30 seconds for "/home/addicttux/...", then other 30 secs for => Booting, then about 3 secs for "use ctrl-c ...",. Thanks to all of you for your support and interest in this blizzard situation

Answer (score 0):

So I just encountered the exact same issue and after trying many things I found out that something was wrong with **webpacker**.

The way I discovered webpacker was the problem was by installing the `bumbler` gem and running `bundle exec bumbler --initializers`. This showed my about 46s was lost doing some yarn stuff.

I tried to start the webpack-dev-server (`bin/webpack-dev-server` but this gave me the following error:

```
Class constructor ServeCommand cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I managed to solve that issue by downgrading the `webpack-dev-server` version in my `package.json` (as explained in this github issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2272)

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.7.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "~3"
}
```

I first removed my `node_modules` folder again and then ran `yarn install`.

After this I could succesfully run `bin/webpack-dev-server` and all of a sudden my rails boot time went from **56s** to **5s**!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know.